# displaying data using reactjs

Tags: php, reactjs

Am trying to display content from database using reactjs but the code keeps on displaying loadings.... and does not print any result.
But i alert the result eg **alert(res);** it prints the data. I think the problem lies in the line of code  **`<MainBox data={this.state.data} />`**

below is the code

```
var MainBox = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    return { data: null };
  },

  componentDidMount: function() {
    $.get('jeck2.php').done(function(data) {
      this.setState({data: data});
//var res=this.state.data;
//alert(res);
    }.bind(this));
  },

  render: function() {
    if (this.state.data) {


return (
      <div>
        <MainBox data={this.state.data} />
      </div>
    );



    }

    return <div>Loading...</div>;
  }
});
```

below is jeck2.php

```
  <div align="center" style="width:500px;">

<?php



include('db.php');

$be = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM jeck order by id desc limit 1");

        $be->execute(array());
$allcount = $be->rowCount();


while($row = $be->fetch()){

 $id= htmlentities($row["id"], ENT_QUOTES);
 $name= htmlentities($row["name"], ENT_QUOTES);



?>

<div style="width:500px; height:50px">
  <div>

  <div class="con">
  <span style="padding:5px;">
<?php echo $name; ?>

</span>
  </div>
  </div> 
  <?php } ?>




  </div>
```

Comment: If you `console.log(this.state.data)` in `render` method, is it always empty?

Comment: You are using `MainBox` in the render method of the `MainBox` component itself

Comment: @mesocarlin, it print values in console within renders using console.log(this.state.data) . am just trying to get the values displayed in the renders physically

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many problems in your code.
1_ You are using Mainbox inside Mainbox, this is a cyclic deadlock condition.
2_ You are passing back views in response to jeck2.php. Better pass json data and keep view in react component.
To display your views inside a react component, you would need [dangerouslySetInnerHTML](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml) :

```
render: function() {
  return this.state.data ?
   <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: this.state.data }} />
  : <div>Loading...</div>;
}
```

Comment: your code when implemented shows error  below "react.js:18350 Uncaught Error: `props.dangerouslySetInnerHTML` must be in the form `{__html: ...}`. Please visit  [link](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html) _italic_ **bold** `code`  for more information." can you help check this requesting  link and help me fix the problem

Comment: @linasmnew it seems to be an html, according to jeck2.php script.

Comment: what comes up when you do console.log(data) after it comes back from the server

Comment: try {{ __html: this.state.data.toString() }}

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
<MainBox data={this.state.data} />
```

With

```
<div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: this.state.data.toString() }} />
```

But don't use this method on user submitted data unless you know what you're doing and are properly escaping everything

Comment: did it fix your issue?